# Jpa репозиторий и Sax

Tags: java, spring, jpa, sax

Решил парсить XML файлы с помощью SAX и заливать в бд, но столкнулся с небольшой проблемой: 
Есть классы: 
-public class MySaxHandler extends DefaultHandler

-public class SaxParser

В SaxParser:
handler = new MySaxHandler();
parser.parse(is,handler);

И получается, что создаю экземпляр класса и передаю его в параметре.
Сама проблема в том, что если я так делаю, в класс MySaxHandler  не передается
@Autowired
Repository

Вопрос: как можно это обойти? Заранее спасибо

Comment: У  меня в MySaxHandler  выполняется логика программы..

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, надо сделать `MySaxHandler` бином и не создавать его вручную, а получать из контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто: делаем через @Autowired